# Implement CustomFeignLogger for feign interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, feign

I have this interface:

```
@FeignClient(name = "${test.feign.name}", url = "${test.feign.url}", configuration = TestConfiguration.class)
public interface TestFeignClient {
    @GetMapping(value = "/users", produces = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<?> getAll();
}
```

And I want to track the log by creating this class `CustomFeignLogger`.
This `CustomFeignLogger` object should `extends Slf4jLogger` Object and override this method:

```
 protected Response logAndRebufferResponse(String configKey,
                                            Level logLevel,
                                            Response response,
                                            long elapsedTime)
      throws IOException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      return super.logAndRebufferResponse(configKey, logLevel, response, elapsedTime);
    }
    return response;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `TestConfiguration` class you need to inject new bean `CustomFeignLogger`

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CustomFeignLogger feignLogger() {
        return new CustomFeignLogger();
    }
}
```

Then you need to override `logAndRebufferResponse` method tike this:

```
   protected Response logAndRebufferResponse(String configKey, Logger.Level logLevel, Response response, long elapsedTime) throws IOException {

        String responseBody = null;
        String reason = response.reason() != null && logLevel.compareTo(Logger.Level.NONE) > 0 ? " " + response.reason() : "";
        int status = response.status();
        this.log(configKey, "<--- HTTP/1.1 %s%s (%sms)", status, reason, elapsedTime);


        // ---------------- Logging headers ----------------
        Iterator headersIterator = response.headers().keySet().iterator();
        while(headersIterator.hasNext()) {
            String field = (String) headersIterator.next();
            Iterator valuesIterator = Util.valuesOrEmpty(response.headers(), field).iterator();

            while(valuesIterator.hasNext()) {
                String value = (String)valuesIterator.next();
                this.log(configKey, "%s: %s", field, value);
            }
        }
        // -------------------------------------------------

        //----------------- Logging response body ---------------
        int bodyLength = 0;
        if (response.body() != null
                && status != HttpStatus.SC_NO_CONTENT
                && status != HttpStatus.SC_RESET_CONTENT) {
                this.log(configKey, "");

            byte[] bodyData = Util.toByteArray(response.body().asInputStream());
            bodyLength = bodyData.length;
            if (bodyLength > 0) {
                String body = Util.decodeOrDefault(bodyData, Util.UTF_8, "Binary data");
                responseBody = body.toString();
                this.log(configKey, "%s", body);
            }

            this.log(configKey, "<--- END HTTP ttttt (%s-byte body)", bodyLength);
           // trackingService.track

            return response.toBuilder().body(bodyData).build();
        }
        this.log(configKey, "<--- END HTTP  tttt (%s-byte body)", Integer.valueOf(bodyLength));
        // -------------------------------------------------

        return response;
    }
```